# Compare both keys and Values of two Maps containing <String, Object>

Tags: java

I have 2 Maps,

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

map1 has {SD="BBBBBB", DNN="Internet", SST=2}
map2 has {SD="BBBBBB", DNN="Internet", SST=2}


map1.equals(map2) => false
```

I need the output as true. What I need to use for it ?

Comment: Are you sure that the strings are equal, e.g. do they contain non-printable characters in one of the maps?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre].

Comment: What if `SST=2` has a `2L` and the other one an integer? And what if `DNN="Internet"` is just a `toString()` of two completely different types of objects? We wouldn't know. Please add a full description including the data types, etc.

Comment: No they dont have any non-printable Chars. When I printed the hashCode() I got 2 diff ids for 2 maps. should it be same ?

Comment: Have you implemented Equals/Hashcode for the object that is inside your map.

Comment: I have not implemented any. I used java.util.Map method. The equals when I used for <String,String> it worked, but not for <String, Object>

Comment: You have to debug your both maps in the debugger to compare their actual values types. Types must be the same. What confuses you is that those implementations _most likely_ have equivalent `toString` outcomes so you cannot distinguish them (just like @ernest_k mentioned). Additionally, your question heavily lacks the way you put entries to your maps, so no answers, only guesses.

Comment: Is one of the 2s an `Integer` and one a `Long`?

Comment: If the strings or Integer are put to both maps of the same type, they are equal [online demo](https://ideone.com/znHLzV)

Answer (score 4):

> I need the output as true. What I need to use for it ?

Well, equal maps.

According to the [Javadoc for `Map.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Returns true if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps m1 and m2 represent the same mappings if `m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())`.

`HashMap` has a correct `equals` implementation; so the conclusion you can draw is that the entry sets actually aren't equal.

It's easy for the string representation of a Java object to look the same as another (e.g. `"0"`, `Integer.valueOf(0)` and `Long.valueOf(0)` all print as `0`); it's also possible for Strings to contain non-printable characters, e.g. `"0\0"` and `"0"` will print the same, but are not equal. And, of course, if you're using custom objects, you need to ensure that `equals` and `hashCode` are implemented correctly.

Check both keys and values in both sets, to see which one causes them not to be equal.

For example:

```
Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>> entrySet1 = new HashSet<>(map1.entrySet());
entrySet1.removeAll(map2.entrySet());
if (!entrySet1.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("Entries only in map1: " + entrySet1);
}

Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>> entrySet2 = new HashSet<>(map2.entrySet());
entrySet2.removeAll(map1.entrySet());
if (!entrySet2.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("Entries only in map2: " + entrySet2);
}
```

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri as I noted in a comment, "`// Similarly with the roles of map1 and map2 reversed.`", meaning _you need to check the other way round too_. I've edited it to be more explicit now.

Comment: Yeah this is the output I have got :
Entry SD="BBBBBB" not in map2
Entry DNN="Internet" not in map2
Entry SST=2 not in map2
Entry SD="BBBBBB" not in map1
Entry DNN="Internet" not in map1
Entry SST=2 not in map1

Comment: @divya ok, so look at those entries with your debugger to find why they're not equal.

Comment: The 1st map is created from jsonNode , so SD,DNN are TextNode and SST is IntNode whereas the map2 have Integer and Strings. How can I convert these TextNode & IntNode to normal Strings nd Integers.